# Filtering and displaying mySQL Data on Webpage via Python? PHP?

Tags: php, python, mysql

I'd like to build a website that reads data from a database, lets me filter that data with different Frontend dropdown-filters and presents me the filtered data in a table shown on the Webpage.

In addition I'd like to have the possibility to use that data further to store it into some file, or use it in a python script that handles that data further.

Should I build the webpage using PHP or what would you recommend me?
I'm new on this area so I don't know much about website interaction yet, just have some experience writing python scripts until now.

Thank you for advices.

Comment: This is the wrong site for this kind of questions since all answers will be 100% opinion based. (Read more here: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)). Either language can do what you want, try one of them, or both, and make your own decision depending on what fits you the best.

Comment: Yup, sorry. Wasn't hoping for the 100% perfect answer anyways, just a few possibilities that I can dig into and choose myself from.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how familiar you are with PHP or Python. If you are new to both, I recommend you to start with [PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/). If you are familiar with Python, I recommend you to use [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/tutorial/) or [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/) to make your project.